# build error in blackberry in rhomobile

Tags: rhomobile

When i try to build for blackberry in Rhomobile it throws the following error.

build started

PWD: C:\Users\Desktop\rhomobile-rhodes-system-api-samples-3.4.2-14-g78b8ea2\rhomobile-rhodes-system-api-samples-78b8ea2
CMD: rake run:bb:device
cd C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.1.1.7/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-3.4.2
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'run:bb:device'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
RET: 1
Error in build application

How to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder where the build.yml file exists of your code and type rake device:bb:production, that should do the trick.